# How to Use some DataTable for a Client Report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, dataset, reporting

I have a client report (RDLC) with these specifications. and I am using VS 2008 to implement this

[image: Client Report Specification]

I have a `DataSet` with 4 Different `DataTable` for each section. and note that all of the report located in a `List` in order to print a large group of Data with one request.

**Description**

1. all of the report located in a List // to print some different data with one request
2. At top (in the list) we have a rectangle which include some Textbox to represent common Information
3. At Middle I have 2 different List which include some TextBox To represent List of Professor and Managers ( it also has to show their Picture, with Name and etc)
4. Then I have another List to represent The Organizations Information. ( it use some TextBox inside of a List to represent All of the Organizations Information)
5. As Client Report work with One Dataset. I provide **four `DataTable`** for my different Report Sections.
6. Each `DataTable` Has an `ID` for `Grouping`
7. The **Common DataTable ID** use to group the entire of the list for another Object (Here University)

How Can I implement Such a report, While I can't use Different `DataTable` for grouping because If I do such a Thing I can Display only the **`First Field`** of the groups

Any Help is Appriciated

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way will be to create an unnormalized data-view by joining your four data tables and then bind your report to it. You have group on ID (that is common to all data tables).

Yet another option would be to use sub-reports but IMO, its more complicated/inefficient to use them instead of above option.